# apache creates more then one process

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am running django application in apache using mod wsgi. I have set server limit to 1 as of the following configuration.

### 00-mpm.conf

```
<IfModule worker.c>
    StartServers         1
    ServerLimit          1
    #MaxClients         300
    MinSpareThreads     25
    MaxSpareThreads     75
    ThreadsPerChild     25
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

At beginning apache runs with one server. But after some time when i am checking it runs with two servers. And i got the following error in the error.log

```
[mpm_worker:notice] [pid 46754:tid 139924109117568] AH00297: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart.
```

How can i make sure that apache to run with only one server. And not doing restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache runs a parent process and then one child worker process with that configuration. The parent process would be quite small in size as all it is doing is managing the child worker process and restarts it if it dies etc. Requests are only handled by the child worker process. So what you are seeing is normal.

Why are you trying to restrict it to one process? If it is to satisfy some requirement of your WSGI application that can only have one process, you should not be using embedded mode anyway. Use daemon mode of mod_wsgi, in which case the WSGI application will use one process by default.

So put back the Apache MPM settings and then use:

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

WSGIDaemonProcess myapp
WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/myapp.wsgi process-group=myapp application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

This will result in the Apache parent process, however many child worker process Apache needs to accept and proxy requests, and the single mod_wsgi daemon process running the WSGI application, to which the child worker processes are proxying requests.

Comment: Hi,
  By adding the above change, apache created daemon process and other apache workers proxies the request to daemon, But still apache restarts the daemon process in a interval (~6hrs). Can i stop this behaviour. How to make sure deamon process not getting restart.

thanks.

Comment: It is likely the ``logrotate`` system on your computer which is set up to restart certain services on regular basis so that it can rotate log files. You would need to disable that and configure Apache to use its own log file rotation mechanism.